# Using a name of the system variable in the referenced DLL of CSPROJ

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Windows 7 x64, MS Visual Studio 2013 Premium.

I created a new system variable `ObjectARX 2009` with the `D:\SDK\Autodesk\AutoCAD\ObjectARX 2009` value. Windows Explorer opens right location for `%ObjectARX 2009%`. I want use this variable in my CSPOJ-file for the references:

```
<Reference Include="AcMgd">
  <HintPath>$(ObjectARX 2009)\inc-x64\AcMgd.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

But Visual Studio doesn't see `AcMgd.dll` file.

[image]

File exists: .NET Reflector opens it for `%ObjectARX 2009%\inc-x64\AcMgd.dll` way.

If I use full path, then it works fine:

```
<Reference Include="AcMgd">
  <HintPath>D:\SDK\Autodesk\AutoCAD\ObjectARX 2009\inc-x64\AcMgd.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

Also, fine works such variant:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ObjectARX_Location>D:\SDK\Autodesk\AutoCAD\ObjectARX 2009</ObjectARX_Location>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="AcMgd">
    <HintPath>$(ObjectARX_Location)\inc-x64\AcMgd.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>False</Private>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Why Visual Studio doesn't see my reference with the **system** variable?

Comment: You basically answered your own question.  VS doesn't do this because just about everybody has a very hard time troubleshooting an "it doesn't work" problem.  Doomed to happen sooner or later, the environment that VS uses is quite invisible.  It is not a wildly popular request, [this one](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2684622-build-output-intermediate-path-configuration-sho) is perhaps closest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a space in the variable name is asking for trouble.

Why not name it **ObjectARX_2009** with an underscore?